# Nginx second domain rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, domain, rewrite, rules

What im trying to do:

I have nginx running with wordpress

Now i want DOMAIN-2 to redirect to a path of DOMAIN-1

```
http://DOMAIN-1/Content-for-Domain-2
```

but not just a simple redirect, it should change to

```
http://DOMAIN-2/Content-for-Domain-2
```

So that users can go to DOMAIN-2 directly if they want to see that content or enter normaly with DOMAIN-1

Any suggestions? I think this should be do-able with rewrite rules?

Comment: I believe the following would do the trick

Source:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703772/htaccess-redirect-to-new-domain-with-path-intact-for-both-www-and-non-www-as-we

Comment: No, i want the new domain to go to the path of the old domain but with  the new domain infront of it.

Comment: For this you need a CNAME DNS record and setup application to use multiple hosts. See my answer for more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

To do this first you have to set CNAME DNS records of DOMAIN-2 and point it to DOMAIN-1.

After that, adjust you nginx configuration for your virtual host. You will have your server_name directive defined like this:

```
server_name DOMAIN-1;
```

You have to update it to this so nginx also accepts requests for DOMAIN-2:

```
server_name DOMAIN-1 DOMAIN-2;
```

E.g.

```
server_name example.com example.net;
```

Comment: And how do i end up to only a special path with this setup? I want to be pointed to Domain2.com/path-i-want. This setup you posted will just  allow me to go to the homepage of domain 1, isnt it like this?